# Xcode UICollectionview Cell Align Left

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionview where each row contains 3 cells. Whenever there isn't 3 cells in a row, the cells will align to the middle. I want them to align left. How do I accomplish this?

The image below shows my problem. How do I align Cell 4 to the left?

[image]

This is the current code I have the controls the sizes and insets:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10);
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

    return CGSizeMake(screenWidth/3-20, 80); //three cells per row

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Surely this behaviour is the standard behaviour of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`?

Comment: @RoboticCat, as per standard behaviour the collectionview cells always start from left.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CGRect screenBound  = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] 
        float colum = 3.0;
     float spacing = 10.0;
    float value = floorf((Float(screenwith) - (colum - 1) * spacing) / 
     colum)

    return CGSizeMake(value, value); //three cells per row

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late but, I had a similar issue and found this solution, might help others in the future.

subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout and override the below method works great.

open class LeftAlignedFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

```
override open func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)

    var leftMargin = sectionInset.left
    var maxY: CGFloat = -1.0
    attributes?.forEach { layoutAttribute in
        if layoutAttribute.frame.origin.y >= maxY
                   || layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x == sectionInset.left {
            leftMargin = sectionInset.left
        }

        if layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x == sectionInset.left {
            leftMargin = sectionInset.left
        } else {
            layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x = leftMargin
        }

        leftMargin += layoutAttribute.frame.width
        maxY = max(layoutAttribute.frame.maxY, maxY)
    }

    return attributes
}
```

}